# Reading reading pdf paragraph text along with css (color etc) using itext

Tags: itext7

I have pdf with tables and cells and i have added paragraph with formatted text in the cell, i need to read list of all tables and followed by text in paragraph with some css(some text highlighted in color), let me know how to start with this, any link where i can go through.

Using iText7

Thanks
Daya

Comment: There are no css in pdfs in general. Are you dealing with pdfs with specific properties (e.g. accordingly tagged ones) or arbitrary ones?

Comment: thanks mkl, i have converted PDF to xlsx - which helped in identifying font (size,color,name).

Answer (score 0):

These are lots of pages to go through CSS, use them and get a bit known about CSS. W3SCHOOLS is a good place to go through them :)

Comment: my question is here how to read paragraph text along with formatted text color etc in pdf using itext pdf, I can create pdf document using tables with cells and their by adding paragraph with text, and the same thing i need to read, not plain text

Answer (score 0):

i have converted PDF to xlsx - which helped in identifying font size,color,name.